# How common is it for a mother duck to adopt ducklings?

Tags: bird-behaviour, ducks

There is a [recent story](https://petapixel.com/2018/08/02/photographer-spots-mother-duck-with-giant-brood-of-76-ducklings/) of how one mother duck kept adopting more ducklings that weren't hers and eventually ended up with **76 ducklings**.

This is called "brood amalgamation", **how common is it among ducks?**

Comment: The concept in itself is not too weird. We cared for a lost duckling ones too. We managed to release it again and a mother duck accepted it following her. It was pretty clearly not the original mother, the other ducklings were a bit bigger, which is why our duckling got left behind again trying to come ashore with the rest. They all made the jump up, our little one disn't. But the mother didn't chase it away. 76 ducklings has to be a special case though.